# ¿Cómo afecta 'h' la pronunciación de 'g'?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, letras

¿Se pronunciaría la palabra hipotética *ghi* como *gi / ji* `/xi/` o *gui* `/gi/`?

<sub>**Nota:** La única palabra que conozco que contiene la secuencia *gh* es [*ghanés(a)*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JAo1LXB).</sub>

Comment: La empresa de mi padre se llama Ghenova y allí todo el mundo la pronuncia como si la "h" no existiera. Es muda, a fin de cuentas...

Comment: Como la h es muda, no provoca ning´ñun efecto en ({a,o,u} (Ghanés= ganés). Sin embargo, yo no pronunciaría "ghe" como "ge" sino como "gue". Quizá es por "contaminación" de otros idiomas.

Comment: @Charlie hay circunstancias en cuales no es 'muda' exactamente - ej. *ch* o *hua-, hue-, hui-*: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=h Pensaba que, por la influencia de ej. italiano, podría actuar como la *u* en *gu* antes de *e/i*. Pero es interesante lo del nombre de la empresa de tu padre - gracias, me pregunto si es así generalmente/con otros nombres propios.

Answer (score 1):

Una palabra con el digrafo *gh* seguramente sería extranjera, así que toca preguntar cómo se pronuncia en su lengua de origen y tratar razonablemente de imitarlo. De hecho, *ghi* es una manera de escribir el hindú घी, que significa “mantequilla clarificada” y *creo* que se pronuncia parecido al comienzo de *jeans* (si alguien tiene mejor información edito).

Comment: Por eso dije “una manera de escribir...”. De hecho _ ee_ viene de la transcripción inglesa, donde se usa para describir el sonido evitando confusión con el sonido de “i corta” como en _bit_; la manera de describir el sonido en español sería “i” y por eso la preferí.

Answer (score 1):

No hay ninguna palabra castellana nativa que emplee la combinación *gh*, ni ninguna manera concebible de que pudiera formarse con elementos nativos o como neologismo culto tomado del latín o del griego. *Ghana* es el nombre de un país cuyo idioma oficial es hoy el inglés y allí la combinación *gh* se pronuncia /ɡ/; por alguna razón en castellano no ha sufrido la normalización ortográfica que sí afectó a países como Catar (*Qatar*).

Un hablante de castellano que haya tenido cierta exposición al italiano o a nombres personales o topónimos tomados tal cual del italiano tenderá a pronunciar *gh* como /ɡ/ (como en *ga, gue, gui, go, gu*). Quien conozca la palabra *ghee*, probablemente lo mismo; no sé cómo se pronuncia hoy en día, pero su raíz en sánscrito tiene una /ɡʱ/, una G murmurada (mal llamada "aspirada"), fonema que se conserva en hindostaní (es /ɡ/ pero con un leve retraso en el comienzo de la vibración de las cuerdas vocales, similar a la aspiración de las oclusivas sordas iniciales en inglés, por ejemplo). Con respecto al inglés, por más que mucha gente hoy está expuesta a él, no creo que muchos estemos tentados de pronunciar *gh* como /f/ o cero, sino más bien como /ɡ/, como es en *Ghana*, *Afghanistan*, el préstamo *ghee* y alguna otra.

No parece que *gh* pudiera pronunciarse igual que *j*, pero si alguien ve escrita la palabra *Ghenova* es probable que pronuncie *Génova* porque pensará que se trata de una forma curiosa o caprichosa de escribir el nombre de esta conocida ciudad, y quizá (sólo quizá) si vuelve a ver otra palabra con *gh* quizá la pronuncie como *j* (como en *ge, gi*).